# Adding Mask to ASPxTextBox for viewing only last 4 digits of a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I need to add a Mask/DisplayFormatString to view only last 4 digits in DevExpress  for all ASPxTextBox s  that refers AccountNumber in the project .  There  is  a common that  method  that return  formatted account number , when pass  the account number .

How can I  call  this  method  or  is there  easy way to  apply this mask to all AccountNumber ASPxTextBoxs in  all over the project. Can you please  help me on this.

Example : If the real account number is  987654321. Then it should display as *****4321

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBankAccountNumber" ClientInstanceName="txtBankAccountNumber" runat="server" Width="100%">
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions!

Comment: The masking core is essentially same with dupe link above, but using different event handler: in `ASPxTextBox` you can try `TextChanged` event (note that displayed string must not change its value). Also add `<MaskSettings PromptChar=" " />` to hide mask placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following examples for setting the Mask to ASPxTextBox

https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/Features/MaskedInput.aspx

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q345434/aspxtextbox-how-to-set-mask

e.g.

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" Width="100%" Caption="Zip Code">
    <MaskSettings Mask="00000" ErrorText="Please input missing digits" />
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" Display="Dynamic" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can masking with 2 ways :

1) Devexpress :

You can use devexpress , you can use masking with phonenumber or etc.

Like this code:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Width="100%" ClientInstanceName="clTxtPhone" Caption="Phone Number">
                <MaskSettings Mask="0000" IncludeLiterals="None" />
                <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" Display="Dynamic" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" />
                <ClientSideEvents Init="phone_InitAndKeyUp" KeyUp="phone_InitAndKeyUp" />
            </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

2) Javascript : 
Like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Example jQuery Reference -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<!-- Example jQuery Masking Script -->
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        // Define your mask (using 9 to denote any digit)
        $('#YourTextBox').mask('(999) 999-9999');
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Example of your TextBox -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</body>
</html>
```